# SOQL SELECT result to Boolean variable

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to get the result of a SOQL query directly into a Boolean variable, something like this:

```
Boolean isParent = [SELECT IsParent__c FROM Tab__c WHERE Id = 123456];
```

I get this error:

> Illegal assignment from List to Boolean

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the IsParent__c value from the SOQL at the end

```
Boolean isParent = [SELECT IsParent__c FROM Tab__c WHERE Id = 123456].IsParent__c;
```

If you are not always sure that this SOQL will return a record(record with that id could be deleted) then this way of accessing will return in an `QueryException`

If this is true, i would assign it to a list sObject variable and then extract value from there that way i know my code is clean and wont error out

Comment: If there aren't any responsive records, you'll get a `QueryException` rather than a `NullPointerException`.